# Trouble starting windows phone 8 emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8, hyper-v

I have windows 8.1 pro with visual studio 2013.I make a simple project and when I run it it gives this error "0x80131500". I enabled hyper-v from bios and from windows but still the same error occurs . There is some problem in virtual switches I guess , Can any one give a step by step procedure to configure virtual switches?

When I goes to hyper-v manager there are no virtual machine running, not found on server . When I click "Virtual Switch Manager" it gives error "An error occurred while trying to retrieve list of virtual switches" . Need help to configure this.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these threads and try troubleshooting the emulator.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681694(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681694%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/b06cc9f2-aa5e-4cb3-9df1-0c273e1dfd68/wp8-emulator-xde-troubleshooting-tips?forum=wptools

For the Virtual Switch error, if you have already configured one or more switches in Hyper-V, run the PowerShell cmdlet Get-VMSwitch and see what the output is.

Hope it helps :)